# How to detect if a specified amount is NaN and how to

Tags: javascript

Okay, so I on my site people play with coins now the feature where you go to use the coins can be "Cheated" by using console in javascript using a string that is NaN so I wan't to know how I can filter if the string inputted in the bets are NaN and if they are not a number I wan't to pop up an error message and if they are numbers I want it to continue with the rest of the script.

Comment: Post what you've tried. Also if you typed in what you're asking here into Google you would probably get an answer in about 5 seconds.

Comment: Clearly didn't try to research this...and research is expected before asking questions

Answer (score 0):

If you want check that something is not a number you should use [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function.

```
 isNaN(NaN) // true
 isNaN(2) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(coins !== coins) {    
     //show alert
     console.info('coins is NaN.');
}
else {
        //do your work
}
```

if your are using ES6 :

```
Number.isNaN(coins)? console.info('coins is NaN.'):console.info('coins is Number.');
```